Why is 'spendthrift' not thrifty? Any other words like this?
The composition of 'spendthrift' lures ones to think it means being thrifty about spending money, but it actually means the opposite. Why does this happen?
Are there other words like this? By 'this', I mean they mean the opposite of what their compositions appear to suggest.

"Why does this happen?" Have you tried looking at the etymology of the word? https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/spendthrift

An EL&U question asked a similar thing in 2014 Spendthrift vs Thrifty - origins

And following my instincts led me to an older question on this site, which essentially asks the same question.

Does this answer your question? The meaning of spendthrift

Note that spendthrift is a noun. It denotes a person who is spendthrifty (exhibits the behavioural trait of spendthiftiness).
All three of those highlighted terms are in the full Oxford English Dictionary, but only the first is used very often.
According to the OED, back in 1350, thrift meant Savings, earnings, gains, profit; acquired wealth, estate, or substance.
The sense of sparing use or careful expenditure of means; frugality didn't arrive until 1570. And while it's true that spendthrift wasn't recorded until 30 years later, it's reasonable to suppose that most people still thought of thrift as meaning acquired wealth - hence spendthrift would naturally be understood as simply meaning "one who spends his wealth".

I may be wrong, but I think that older sense of thrift (first recorded 1305 with definition the fact or condition of thriving or prospering) was particularly associated with "unexpectedly" acquired or "unearned" wealth, so a typical spendthrift would be someone who "came into" money they might not ordinarily have had. Similar to football pools winners today, in which context we also use the verb blue / blow - to squander (money).

Shouldn't spendthriftyness be spelt with an "i"? I was beginning to feel excited when I saw it because I thought it might be an exception to the rule--I'm always on the lookout for idiosyncrasies--but I checked online and it's not the typical spelling.

Does the betting game "football pools" still exist in the UK? I was under the impression it had been replaced with the Lottery when  football league matches stopped being  played on a Saturday at the same  time. I should look this up but some learners might find this interesting

You're quite right about the spelling, ty! I must have just tacked ness on to the end of the -y adjective without thinking. I don't know the mechanics of it, but I know my octogenarian neighbour still does the pools because he's getting into his dotage and he's told me 2-3 times already this year about winning £15K once when he was younger!

A spendthrift is one who spends their thrift (i.e., their savings, the fruit of their thrift). Thus, thrift actually has the same meaning in this compound as it does normally.
We don't have that many nominal compounds of this form: verb + object. We usually prefer object + agent or object + instrument, e.g. floor cleaner, toothbrush, tree-hugger. One might argue that verb + object is influenced by the standard French compound structure: brosse-dents, gratte-ciel, porte-parole.
But English does have precedents: carry-all, scofflaw, pickpocket. And of this kind is spendthrift.
